# Copy 2 sheets vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy 2 sheets, and save in other file.

I need copy all sheets "Front"
and bottom add Range("A2:N10") from sheets "Cache"

```html
Worksheets("Front").Copy
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    wbNew.SaveAs "C:\______\pl.xlsx"
    wbNew.Close True
```

Result:
New file "pl.xlsx"
where
A1:N25 = Sheets Front

A26:N43 = Sheets Cache :D

Any sugestions ?

Comment: Excel has a great feature, called the [macro recorder](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-record-a-macro-to-automate-tasks-in-excel-2010/).  You can use this to record your manual actions as VBA, for next time.

Comment: What do you mean by copy all sheets "Front"? Is there more than one sheet with the name "Front"?

Comment: I have file xlslx to generate Packing List. In this file i have 2 sheets, FRONT  and cache. I need to copy two sheets to new file (save as). Range to COPY from FRONT A1:N24, RANGE TO COPY from CACHE: is dynamic value - at the moment a2:N10.

Now paste in new file:
-VALUE FROM "FRONT"
-VALUE FROM "CACHE"

I'm make this manual and make screen
http://srv3.sendfile.pl/pobierz/950031---wkfb/5316677400_1326980696.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that worksheets "Front" and "Cache" are in the workbook the macro resides in, then you can type:

```
Sub main()
    Worksheets("Front").Copy '<--| this creates a new workbook with one worksheet that becomes the "active" one
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cache").Range("A2:N10").Copy '<--| 'ThisWorkbook' refers to the workbook the running macro resides in, no matter which is the "active" workbook
    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial '<--| no need to qualify range references up to its worksheet to implicitly assume the "active" one  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

While if worksheets "Front" and "Cache" are NOT in the workbook the macro resides in, then you can type:

```
Sub main2()
    Dim rngToCopy As Range

    Set rngToCopy = Worksheets("Cache").Range("A2:N10") '<--| set the range to copy before changing the "active" workbook with the worksheet 'Copy' method call        
    Worksheets("Front").Copy '<--| this creates a new workbook with one worksheet that becomes the "active" one
    rngToCopy.Copy '<--| copy the range you previously stored
    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial '<--| no need to qualify range references up to its worksheet to implicitly assume the "active" one
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub z()
Dim NewSheet, Cache1, Front1 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Integer
Set Front1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Front")
Set Cache1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cache")
Front1.Copy
Set NewSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
LastRow = Front1.UsedRange.Rows(Front1.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1
Cache1.Range("A2:N10").Copy
NewSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Once the Sheets are declared, it's easy to shove the data around. I tested this part; then run your Save code

Comment: just some (possibly) usefule notes 1) no need for `Set NewSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` statement (and for `NewSheet` declaration as well) since after `Front1.Copy` the newly created workbook becomes the "active" workbook and its only worksheet becomes its "active" worksheet  2) hence `NewSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1).PasteSpecial` can become `Cells(LastRow, 1).PasteSpecial` 3) you can also avoid the declaraton and calculation of `LastRow` as you can see per my answer

Comment: I always declare them so i can switch later